# demonstrate, H(x,z,y)=H(z,y,x) and H(x,y,z)=H(z,x,y)

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

First of all, I have function $F(x,y)= F(y ,x)$, and $y$ and $x$ are vectors. $G(x, y)  =-G(y,x)$. Then $H(x,y,z)=F(x,G(y,z))$. and they are all vectors. Second of all, $H(x,y,z)=H(y,z,x)$. How can I demonstrate $H(x,z,y)=H(z,y,x)$ and $H(x,y,z)=H(z,x,y)$? The functions, $F$, $G$ are all linear by the way.

Comment: $H(x,y,z) = H(y,z,x)$ implies both, since $x,y,z$ are dummy variables.

Comment: and how do i Show H(x,x,y)=0?

Comment: By showing that $H(x,x,y) = F(x,G(x,y)) = -F(x,G(y,x)) = -H(x,y,x) = -H(x,x,y)$.